# Как отправить альбом с помощью aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

У меня есть этот код, он берет видео, если нажать кнопку подтверждения, видео отправляется в админ/чат. Если человек отправляет 2 и более видео, то бот отправляет только первое видео. Как сделать так, чтобы бот отправлял все видео, которые прислал пользователь? ИЛИ лучше, чтобы он просто переслал видео и ответил на него каким-нибудь текстом?

P.S.: Из видео может быть прислан еще какой-то текст (подпись)

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == "confirm", state=NewsSubmission.confirm_submission)
async def confirm_news(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    callback_query.message.reply
    data = await state.get_data()
    city = data['city']
    news_message = data['news']
    if news_message.content_type == 'text':
        await bot.send_message(ADMIN_CHAT_ID, f'Нова новина з <b>{city}</b>\n'
                                            f'Від <b>{callback_query.from_user.full_name}</b>\n'
                                            f'З ніком - <b>@{callback_query.from_user.username}</b>\n\n'
                                            f'<i>{news_message.text}</i>', parse_mode='html')
        await callback_query.message.reply(f"✅ Ваше повідомлення успішно відправлено. Чекайте відповіді від адміністратора.\nЯкщо ви хочете написати ще одне повідомлення, продовжуйте писати у цьому чаті.")
    
    elif news_message.content_type == types.ContentType.PHOTO:
        album = data.get('album')
        m = await bot.send_photo(ADMIN_CHAT_ID, news_message.photo[-1].file_id, caption='news_message.caption')
        await callback_query.message.reply(f"✅ Ваше фото успішно відправлено. Чекайте відповіді від адміністратора.\nЯкщо ви хочете написати ще одне повідомлення, продовжуйте писати у цьому чаті.!")
        await m.reply(f'Нова новина з фото від міста  <b>{city}</b>\n'
                      f'Від <b>{callback_query.from_user.full_name}</b>\n'
                      f'З ніком - <b>@{callback_query.from_user.username}</b>\n\n', parse_mode='html')
        await state.update_data(album=album)
        
        
    elif news_message.content_type == types.ContentType.VIDEO:
        album = data.get('album')
        
        m=await bot.send_media_group(ADMIN_CHAT_ID, news_message.video.file_id, caption=news_message.caption)
        await callback_query.message.reply(f"✅ Ваше відео успішно відправлено. Чекайте відповіді від адміністратора.\nЯкщо ви хочете написати ще одне повідомлення, продовжуйте писати у цьому чаті!")
        await m.reply(f'Нова новина з відео від міста  <b>{city}</b>\n'
                      f'Від <b>{callback_query.from_user.full_name}</b>\n'
                      f'З ніком - <b>@{callback_query.from_user.username}</b>\n\n', parse_mode='html')
        await state.update_data(album=album)

    await state.update_data(news=None)
    await NewsSubmission.submit_news.set()
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял вашу проблему (переводил через переводчик), вам необходимо вместо того, чтобы отправлять сообщение, просто отправлять его копию. Можно использовать метод [copyMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#copymessage), вместо [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage)

Ну или проще говоря замените все

```
await bot.send_...
```

На

```
await bot.copy_message(ADMIN_CHAT_ID,callback_query.from_user.id,callback_query.message.id)
```

или

```
await callback_query.message.copy_to(ADMIN_CHAT_ID)
```

Comment: нет, мне нужно отправлять альбом видео. Хотя как я вас понял, видео с текстом будет пересилатся в другой чат. Если так, то мне подходит такой вариант, но у меня тогда виходит ошибка:
callback_query.message.id)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'copy_message'

Comment: Какая у вас версия aiogram?

Comment: вторая версия. Если можете, помогите с вопросом

Comment: Вообще, по докам все также совпадает https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/v2.25.1/telegram/bot.html#aiogram.bot.bot.Bot.copy_message

Comment: можеш rottenrat помочь мне зделать такую функцию, я цитал доки, и немогу разобраться

Comment: Отправьте код, который у вас получился при замене

Comment: я не юзал ваш код, сечас у меня код, которий в вопросе, и я не могу никак разобраться как зделать отправку по возможности альбома

Comment: Мой способ перессылает сообщение без отображения изначального отправителя. То есть, сообщение полностью перенесется от имени бота. Есть параметр, который заменяет существующий текст: caption

Comment: если юзать способ " перессылает сообщение без отображения" то все фото и видео с текстом будут пересилатся в чат?
Если да, то можете скинуть код, чтоби я его протестировал

Comment: await bot.copy_message(ADMIN_CHAT_ID,callback_query.from_user.id,callback_query.message.id) перессылается все без отображения отправителя

Comment: await bot.copy_message(ADMIN_CHAT_ID,callback_query.from_user.id,callback_query.message.id, caption = "") перессылается все с пустым текстом